# Draw an image with pdfbox Android

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

How to draw an image into a pdf using pdfbox 2.0 library for android or how can i get an Image field from a form in a pdf file?

Comment: *draw an image into a pdf* - do you mean vector graphics like lines and rectangles and curves? Or do you mean bitmaps?

Comment: This seems to be 2 questions in one: draw an image, extract an image in a form. Please edit your question to clarify. And mention whether you tried with desktop PDFBox or not. See also at the bottom of this issue: https://github.com/TomRoush/PdfBox-Android/issues/1

Comment: I had analyze the library of Tom Roush but i didn't fine anything about extract and image in a form and modify it. My question is: How to extract an image from a form into a pdf file and modify it with PdfBox? Thanks